# CuPy import failing due to missing DLL file although it appears in my directories

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, cupy

I am attempting to use cuPy to speed up some background numpy operations in my python code but when attempting to import cupy I am told that the DLL load failed and the module could not be found, cupy_backends.cuda.libs import nvrtc. (Specific errors at end of post)

I've attempted almost everything the error message suggests. I check my version of cupy and cuda which are cupy-cuda111==8.4.0, I have Cuda 11.2 installed as well. I am running Windows 10 and Python 3.7.6 on Spyder 3. I have tried uninstalling cupy via pip uninstall in hopes of reinstalling correctly but it just hangs and never uninstalls the package.

It appears I have the file its looking for when I go search manually via my file explorer. (Imaged Below)

[image: file explorer showing the missing file in question]

I am fairly inexperienced when it comes to handling things like this so any help would be greatly appreciated. The entire error message and trace is copied below:

```
import cupy as cp
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from cupy import core  # NOQA

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cupy.core import core  # NOQA

  File "cupy\core\core.pyx", line 1, in init cupy.core.core

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import compiler  # NOQA

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cupy_backends.cuda.libs import nvrtc

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-e011b0e859cc>", line 1, in <module>
    import cupy as cp

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    raise ImportError(_msg) from e

ImportError: CuPy is not correctly installed.

If you are using wheel distribution (cupy-cudaXX), make sure that the version of CuPy you installed matches with the version of CUDA on your host.
Also, confirm that only one CuPy package is installed:
  $ pip freeze

If you are building CuPy from source, please check your environment, uninstall CuPy and reinstall it with:
  $ pip install cupy --no-cache-dir -vvvv

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

original error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: `cupy-cuda111` is a wheel for CUDA 11.1 and unfortunately won't work with CUDA 11.2. We're actively working on publishing `cupy-cuda112` package (https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/4702). If you need to use CUDA 11.2, please build CuPy from source for now/

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Should I downgrade my CUDA to 11.1 then? and if so how do I do that? Or are you recommending to update CuPy with a build from source and that should hopefully allow me to utilize it now? Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway I can manually remove or uninstall CuPy to try to restart the installation process from scratch? Every time I try "pip uninstall cupy-cuda111" in the Spyder console it just hangs and I have to restart the kernel. Resulting in nothing happening.

Comment: I'd suggest you downgrading to CUDA 11.1 for now. As for Spyder console issue, I don't have any idea why that's happening. Are there any error logs?

Comment: There are no logs. It just hangs the entire time. I resulted to uninstalling and reinstalling my entire anaconda environment. Since you suggested downgrading to CUDA 11.1 for now do you have any recommendations for that? Do I simply uninstall everything from 11.2 or is there more that needs to happen with regards to drivers and such? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can just uninstall everything named CUDA 11.2, and then reinstall CUDA 11.1. When installing CUDA 11.1 you can skip installing a graphics driver.

Comment: FYI, we've published cupy-cuda112 packages. https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/4704

Comment: Thank you! I downgraded from 11.2 to 11.1 and that seemed to help but I'm sure others will appreciate this moving forward as well.